# Can e.g. pip list the options for extras_require?

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I know that I can specify optional dependencies in `setup.py` via [extras_require](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies):

```
setup(
  name="Foo",
  extras_require={
    'bar':  ["barpy"],
  }
)
```

Now, is there a way for a user to list the extras my package offers?  How else would a user know that it might be cool to install the package via

```
pip3 install .[bar]
```

?

Comment: "How else would a user know that it might be cool to install the package via ..." – list the extras in your documentation! :)

Comment: It's being discussed at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4824 and https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3797

Comment: @Josh yes, that's what I'm doing already. :-)

Comment: @phd Thanks, that sounds relevant. Maybe an answer has to wait until there is an implementation.

Answer (score 4):

You can inspect a project's metadata with the new [importlib_metadata](https://pypi.org/project/importlib_metadata):

```
>>> import importlib_metadata
>>> importlib_metadata.metadata('xonsh').get_all('Provides-Extra')
['linux', 'mac', 'proctitle', 'ptk', 'pygments', 'win']
```